# How to add my form data to draft folder if the form is not submitted in Java

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have one test booking page and user fill half data and then leave that page.Before leaving that page i want to store that data somewhere so that i will display that data in draft.

Comment: Let me know this answered your question. Or I will try to solve it by other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax to store data without submitting form.

Or

You can use browsers local storage to store data with the help of HTML5.
HTML local storage provides two objects for storing data on the client:

1. window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date
2. window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost
   when the browser tab is closed)

### Local Storage Object

The localStorage object stores the data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year.

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Example explained :

- Create a localStorage name/value pair with name="lastname" and
  value="Smith"
- Retrieve the value of "lastname" and insert it into the element with
  id="result"

The syntax for removing the "lastname" localStorage item is as follows:

```
localStorage.removeItem("lastname");
```

You can use `localStorage` in your case

Comment: No actually i want save that data if user close that wndow without submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is to have a Save button that submits the partial request without Submitting it.  On the server side, you just save the partially completed form in a database table ... and have your UI provide a way to reload the form when the user comes back.

If you use AJAX or similar, you are sending requests to the server.  Whether you think of this as submitting "the form" or not is a matter of semantics.

If you want to store something in the user's web browser, take a look at the Web Storage API; e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

(I'm not saying this is a good idea ...)

---

> No actually i want save that data if user close that wndow without submitting the form.

So either:

- save periodically,
- save in the window close event handler, or
- ask the users if they want to close the window if there is data in the form.

Comment: No actually i want save that data if user close that wndow without submitting the form